# Rs stepAIC in Python for statsmodels

Tags: python, r, statsmodels, feature-selection

Is there a python equivalent for this R function:

```
stepAIC(model, direction="both")
```

It should be compatible with statsmodels GLM (I use sm.families.NegativeBinomial())

I found this but only forward direction is supported: https://qiita.com/mytk0u0/items/aa2e3f5a66fe9e2895fa ([Python equivalent for R StepAIC for Logistic Regression (direction='Backwards')](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49493468/4928433))

EDIT:
I could use mytk0u0s solution for a backward implementation.
But I don't know how to implement "both".

The direction argument of stepAIC controls the mode of the stepwise model search:

- "backward": removes predictors sequentially from the given model. It produces a sequence of models of decreasing complexity until attaining the optimal one.
- "forward": adds predictors sequentially to the given model, using the available ones in the data argument of lm. It produces a sequence of models of increasing complexity until attaining the optimal one.
- "both" (default): a forward-backward search that, at each step, decides whether to include or exclude a predictor. Differently from the previous modes, a predictor that was excluded/included previously can be later included/excluded.

(https://bookdown.org/egarpor/PM-UC3M/lm-ii-modsel.html)

Comment: Wrote the code but I don't know if I can publish it because it partly based on mytk0u0s solution.